# Try/Catch Loop not triggering catch statement on IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a spring boot application and have a unique object which is persisted in a database, and retrieved by the following CRUD Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface DefaultSurveyRepository extends CrudRepository <DefaultSurvey, UUID> {

    public static final UUID specialId = UUID.fromString("123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-556642440000");


    default DefaultSurvey findSpecialInstance() {
        return findById(specialId).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No Default Survey Found"));
    }
}
```

In my service class constructor, I try to find the specialInstance of the object, and if this fails I create a new version. The code is the following:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AdminManagement {
    
    private final DefaultSurveyRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    public AdminManagement(DefaultSurveyRepository repo) {
        
        //Check if defaultSurvey exists.
        try{
            repo.findSpecialInstance();
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException e){
            repo.save(new DefaultSurvey(UUID.fromString("123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-556642440000"), "[]"));
        }

        this.repo = Objects.requireNonNull(repo);
    }
.
.
.
```

The problem is that it does not catch the IllegalStateException and crashes, if the object does not exist. I have tried setting breakpoints to debug, but it crashes before the breakpoint is reached. Maybe I am not debugging correctly, but I do not understand why it won't work.
Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace you get?

Comment: The code talks about IllegalStateException; you are saying IllegalArgumentException in the question.  Is there really an IllegalArgumentException?  You have no catch clause for that.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using try/catch for ordinary flow control anyway. If you need to ensure that the `DefaultSurvey` exists, add it in some management component like a `CommandLineRunner`.

Comment: @user13784117 there is no IllegalArgumentException, that is a typo sorry

Comment: @Ismail `Error creating bean with name 'adminController' defined in file [/Users/lucian/Documents/qova/qova/target/classes/qova/admin/AdminController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminManagement' defined in file [/Users/lucian/Documents/qova/qova/target/classes/qova/admin/AdminManagement.class]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it would be better to implement CommandLineRunner. Another "simple" option is to leave the initialization details about your repo in @PostConstruct:

```
private final DefaultSurveyRepository repo;

@Autowired
public AdminManagement(DefaultSurveyRepository repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
}

@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() {
    try{
        repo.findSpecialInstance();
    } catch(IllegalStateException e){
        repo.save(new DefaultSurvey(UUID.fromString("123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-556642440000"), "[]"));
}
    this.repo = Objects.requireNonNull(repo);
}
```

Just remember that Java EE annotations have been deprecated in Java9 and removed in Java 11 so you must add that to your Maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>   
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```